# Closing connections to an elasticsearch cluster using elasticsearch-py

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to close a connection to my elasticsearch cluster in my application code using elasticsearch-py.

Currently, I'm using:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
es.close()
```

But, I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 45, in <module>
    es.close()
AttributeError: 'Elasticsearch' object has no attribute 'close'
```

I haven't seen any close methods in the documentation either:

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can close the transport with [`Transport.close`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/connection.html#elasticsearch.Transport.close):

```
es = Elasticsearch()
es.transport.close()
```